# How to install drivers for Broadcom BCM43142 on Kali Linux

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, drivers, network-interface

I'm trying to install drivers for Broadcom BCM43142 on Kali Linux, but all the tutorials I searched for were using apt-get, etc., but I dont have ethernet support, I am on my windows pc right now while writing this.

If anyone could help me install drivers for this, it would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Please note that I do not have any form of internet on the Kali Linux machine.

Comment: yes, dkms is installed, but when i try to install the broadcom-sta-dkms_6.30.223.271-14_all.deb, it says this: Module build for kernel 5.4.0-kali2-686-pae was skipped since the kernel headers for this kernel does not seem to be installed.

Answer (score 1):

First, I installed [linux-headers-5.4.0-kali2-686-pae_5.4.8-1kali1_i386.deb](https://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/l/linux/linux-headers-5.4.0-kali2-686-pae_5.4.8-1kali1_i386.deb)

Then, I installed [dkms_2.6.1-4_all.deb](http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/d/dkms/dkms_2.6.1-4_all.deb)

After that, I installed [broadcom-sta-dkms_6.30.223.271-10_all.deb](http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/non-free/b/broadcom-sta/broadcom-sta-dkms_6.30.223.271-10_all.deb)

Then, I just rebooted my pc and everything worked!

Comment: Could you please add the command you used to install the packages? Thanks!